# Oh no Another BigO one

Tags: math, computer-science, big-o

I've been doing BigO recently, and I get the formula ok, but I've written a piece of code that takes and input and returns a time taken to complete a sort. So I have the input and time, how do I use this to classify what sort of BigO it is? I've made graphs and can see which sort they are but I can't do it using the formula? I'm not strong on maths which I think is my problem here!

For instance I get:

```
Size  Time    Operations
200    2     163648
400    1     162240
800    15    2489456
1600   6     10247376
3200   19    40858160
6400   79    165383984
12800  318   656588080
25600  1274  2624318128
51200  5059  10476803408
102400 20333 41969291968
```

I know that this is O(n^2) by looking at the graph and comparing, but how do I prove it?

Comment: O notation rely on operations number, not on the time in the sense of seconds.

Comment: You can only "prove" it by analyzing the source code rigorously.  No amount of samples can ever "prove" anything.  (Put another way, big-O notation is all about asymptotic behavior; that is, behavior for "sufficiently large" inputs.  There is no fixed definition of "sufficiently large"; you must analyze the algorithm itself.)

Comment: A O(n^2) algorithm is also O(n^n) for example, so it's trivial to just give some ludicrously bad exponential function as the answer, and the answer will be correct. What you're really looking for is Θ, which bounds your running time above and below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can sample a thousand different input sizes, and then try to derive a Big-O value from that, but you shouldn't - not only because it doesn't actually prove anything, but because *that isn't the point*.

The way to prove O(n^2) is to prove it on the *code itself*, not through experiments. The actual running time isn't important, because Big-O notation doesn't say anything about that - in simple terms, it only specifies the *dominant term* of whatever formula you would use to calculate the exact running time, in the sense of the number of operations executed for that function. Constants are thrown away, and so are smaller terms - the actual running time of a function might be 1000n^2+1000000n, but that's still O(n^2).

Comment: That explains why I can't figure it out if I can't see the operations, I've edited my code to show the operations, could someone show how to prove its O(n^2) with that then? I feel the need to see an example relative to my problem.

Comment: @EricBanderhide: No, because you cannot *prove* through samples (and I doubt that number actually reflects the true number of operations, anyway). The best you can do, as mentioned by paxdiablo, is to get a *belief* that it's n^2 - because (2n)^2 = 4(n^2), and your numbers suggest that, for the most part, the time/number of "operations" roughly quadruples when the input size is doubled. Without the *actual code*, however, *nothing can be proven*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mathematically prove anything from this table; the complexity might be O(1) if `Time` remains at 20333 for all larger values.

The best you can do is try fitting several curves to this table and selecting the best fit according to Occam's razor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *prove* it by looking at the timings, you can only prove it by analysing the code to see how many steps are performed. The reason for this is that the time taken is a function not only of your program but many other things outside of your control as well.

For example, who can say whether your machine didn't spend an inordinate amount of time in other processes during one particular test run of your program? This sort of thing can be minimsed to a point using statistical methods but the *proof* requires solid data.

What you *can* do is to look at some of your data points to get *support* for the contention that it's O(n<sup>2</sup>). Have a look at the last four entries:

```
Input       Time
  128        318
  256       1274   1274 /  318 = 4.006
  512       5059   5059 / 1274 = 3.971
 1024      20333  20333 / 5059 = 4.019
```

You can see that each doubling of the input size has a multiplier effect of the time of about 4 which would tend to indicate an O(n<sup>2</sup>) property.

But this is support only. It applies only to that particular range of input values and, as stated, is subject to factors outside your control. Note also that the support would be harder to see if the time taken was not a simple one. For example, if the time function was `t = n2/10 + 123n + 123456789`, it would be a little harder to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

Just by making a comparison between the values may not make any sense.However,if you plot a graph using this values( x-axis : input , y-axis:time),you will get a curve or a linear shape or whatever.Using this information,you can predict the BigO value of that function.Of course there may be(not always) some interrupts that affects the running of that process,but that does not last during the whole period.It is slight overhead that cannot affect the result.
In order to predict the BigO value , you will need some Calculus knowledge in order to make the analogy between the shape and BigO result.

For example,let's say that you got a linear shape and you know that it means O(n).In that point,you reached that result because you know the shape of a linear function graph and your graph looks like it.In order to reach the true proof , you have to draw both your functions curve and the graph  of the mathematical function that has the closest shape to your graph.

There are some other functions like Big-Theta , Small-Omega that binds your function from upper or from lower.The mathematical function could be both of them,but as a result,your Big-O function is the closest one to that shape.